# How to change or hide cursor?

Tags: cursor, npapi, windowless

Hi I am developing a windowless NPAPI plugin. I am drawing the images on the plugin . Now my problem is  change my cursor in windowless plugin.Please can one help me.

Answer (score 1):

How you hide a mouse cursor completely depends on the platform (operating system) you are on, NPAPI doesn't help you with that.

For windowless plugins you should be able to implement [`NPP_HandleEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/NPP_HandleEvent) and e.g. on Windows handle [`WM_SETCURSOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) accordingly 
(i.e. call `SetCursor()`), but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860253/is-it-possible-to-change-the-mouse-cursor-reliably-in-a-windowless-plugin-runnin) suggests that there may be issues with at least Chromes implementation.